# Changes made in dialog-flow doesn't reflect in google actions's testing simulator

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant

Previously "Auto-preview" option was coming in dialog flow under integration section as shown in this below image , but Google discontinued this option from 14 April 2021.
[image]

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/release-notes#April_14_2021

It seems that auto-preview option earlier was responsible for propagate changes of dialog flow to actions, and it reflects in Google Actions' testing simulator.

After removing "Auto-Preview", Is there any alternative way they provided to refresh content?

I am struggling with one issue currently, after making changes in dialog flow text response and saving it, doesn't reflect on Google Actions' test simulator.

Comment: Doesn't it update when you press the Test button again?

Comment: @Nick Feller, no, I tried several times, but it didn't work.

Comment: That is strange, I have just tested it and it worked fine. If you are still experiencing the issue, as it seems to be on the Actions on Google's side, I suggest that you contact the AoG support team directly by submitting a request through their [support form](https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support).

Comment: Thanks @Ksign   for inputs I observed that the error occurred in dialog flow causing this issue, of not updating the changes on Google Actions' simulator. More elaborated in answer.

Comment: Thanks @NickFelker, after finding the cause and playing around a bit, I have observed that on click of "Test" button again reflects the dialog flow text response changes on Google Actions' simulator. No need of alternative for removed Auto-preview option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that described issue of, "changes on dialog flow is not updating Google Actions's simulator" encountered because of error occurred in dialog flow, which is showing on click of "Test" button, that's error resulted into, not updating google actions's simulator.

[image]

[image]

```
Errors in 'DoorStatus' intent:
IntentDoorStatus has more than 128 training phrases. Reduce the number of training phrases to 10 or remove the intent from Implicit invocation.
com.google.dialogflow.designtime.exceptions.DesigntimeException: <eye3 title='FAILED_PRECONDITION'/> generic::FAILED_PRECONDITION: Errors in 'DoorStatus' intent:
IntentDoorStatus has more than 128 training phrases. Reduce the number of training phrases to 10 or remove the intent from Implicit invocation.
```

So, just to check I tried by removing some of the implicit invocation intents(e.g DoorStatus, DoorOpen etc.), those generating errors and tried testing without those intents. This time, it has updated the Actions successfully and now changed text response in dialog flow is reflecting on simulator.

**Needs to improve:**
In current flow, on click of the "Test" button (Inside Dialog Flow's Integration section), dialog flow navigates to Google Actions simulator regardless of error occurred in dialog flow. Dialog flow is showing the error in case it occurs, but since dialog flow redirects to simulator although error occurred, it seems that to developer as the changes which they did, will be reflected on simulator, but actually those changes won't reflect in simulator due to dialog flow error.

In this case of error in dialog flow, dialog flow should not redirect to Google Actions simulator. It should only allow to navigate to google actions' simulator, when dialog flow part builds successfully without any error. By preventing to navigate on simulator in case of dialog flow error , will help developer to aware about any occurred dialog flow error and provide  hint to fix that error first before testing on simulator.